# Problem in writing the system of equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

Here's the code I have and here's the system of equation it creates which is not working as desired. Do you know how I can fix it?

```
\item For what value of $b$ would the following system fo equations have an infinite number of solutions?\hfill
$$\begin{align*} 
3x+5y &=  27 \\ 
12x+20y &=  3b
\end{align*}$$
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $9$   
    \item $27$ 
    \item $36$
    \item $81$ 
    \item $126$             
    \end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't add the outer `$$`s, then you'll be fine. Also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy) for when a display math block is needed.

Answer (score 8):

A suggestion to improve the below solution, using `in-line` enumerate* environment from the `enumitem` package, and `empheq` (that loads amsmath) to have a left brace before the system of equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start = 55]
\item For what value of $b$ would the following system fo equations have an infinite number of solutions?
\begin{align*}[left = \empheqlbrace]
3x+5y &= 27 \\
12x+20y &= 3b
\end{align*}
    \begin{enumerate*}[afterlabel = ~~, itemjoin = {\hspace{1.5em}} ]
    \item $9$
    \item $27$
    \item $36$
    \item $81$
    \item $126$.
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The package [systeme](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/systeme) is very handy for typesetting systems of equations. Note how not just the `=` symbol but also the variables `x` and `y` and the symbol `+` are aligned nicely without requiring any special user inputs (see the comment in my code).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme} % see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/systeme
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item For what value of $b$ would the following system of equations 
   have an infinite number of solutions?
\[
\sysdelim..  % no delimiter symbols on either side
\systeme{
   5y+3x =  27 , % it will be automatically reordered as 3x+5y = 27
   12x+20y =  3b}
\]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 9   
    \item 27 
    \item 36
    \item 81 
    \item 126             
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer - Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5):

The `align*` environment (as well as `align`) is *already* a math environment, so you don't need to go into math mode before using `align*`. In fact, `align*` can *not* be used in math mode, but the "inner" math environments such as `aligned` can be.

[image]

### References:

- You don't need to use `\[` in this particular case, but you should have a look at [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)
- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[55.] For what value of $b$ would the following system of equations have an infinite number of solutions?
        \begin{align*} 
             3x+ 5y &=  27 \\ 
            12x+20y &=  3b
        \end{align*}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $9$   
            \item $27$ 
            \item $36$
            \item $81$ 
            \item $126$             
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you test your code? When I am testing it , it doesn't become the same as yours!

Comment: @MonaJalal: Yes I did. The image is the output of the code as posted.  Did you try the code exactly as I posted, or did you try it in your real use case? Perhaps you are using different packages, or have some custom settings? There is a reason why it is recommended that you post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate reproduces the problem. Please provide more details and then perhaps we can figure out the problem.